# Accessing an aggregate from another aggregate in an Event Sourcing Microservice architecture based on Domain Driven Design

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, event-sourcing, eventual-consistency

Let's say we've got three aggregates, Asset(assets of a user), Income(contains user income sources) and  Profile(contains entities and values related to managing user profiles). Now a user Profile status can be updated either through an Income change or an Asset change. But here's the catch, any change should take both Asset and Income to account and for that the Profile service needs to keep track of Assets and Incomes.

How may we tackle this with event sourcing. I mean is it a good practice to keep a local store updated in Profile service for Asset and Income aggregates ? If so, then we need to tackle the eventual consistency concerns. Is there another approach to this ?

Comment: How would you do it if you weren't doing event sourcing?

Answer (score 0):

Use a transaction in your application service and save the three aggregate in the three different repositories, that way you ensure consistency. I assume they are all in the same container.

If you are talking about eventual consistency, it may be not the case so if they belong to different bounded context, you can implement a listener (inbound port adapter) on the receiver BC, which will eventually update the aggregate in response to this event.